# Glitches when using simple screen recorder on Arch Linux box

Tags: archlinux, desktop-recording

So i had been making video tutorials for my friends on how to program. On my old computer i had been all ways running simple screen recorder and it recorded fine. But recently i got a new computer. And so when i got a fresh install of arch linux on the box. I set up the environment with every thing i needed to make another video. When i downloaded simple screen recorder using yaourt, and started recording. I had recorded up to a two hour session with out knowing that it was glitching out. When i look at my computer i do not see the same issue as when the final product is done rendering. I think it might be a rendering error or i do not have the right codecs. After a hour or two searching on the web i could find no forum posts on the codec. I took in multiple things that could be wrong with it fps was my first choice but when i had recorded with 25 and even 50 fps it was still glitching out. The next idea i had was that i had the wrong codec H.264. But with searching i could find no solution to that one. Then i thought that i might have been encoding at to high of a speed (23). But still that proved me wrong. so now i am confused with how to get my answer.

Settings Screen shot:
[image: Settings Screen One]
[image: Settings Screen Two]

Video Link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zfyIZiJCDa4

Answer (score 1):

The glitches are often relate to the rendering backend of the window compositor you are using.

### Solution 1 - Change the rendering backend of the window compositor

@thouliha reported having issues with compton. In my case I had glitches with openGL (2.0 & 3.1) and resolved the issue by switching to XRender for recording.

On KDE you easily change the rendering backend of the window compositor in the settings [image: compositor settings].

### Solution 2 - Change the Tearing Prevention method

To keep using OpenGL, for example for better performance, you can also tweak the tearing prevention method.

In my case switching from Automatic to Never allowed me to record video with OpenGL compositor without glitches.

### Solution 3 - Intel iGPU specific issues

Intel iGPU (Intel graphics) has some rendering issues with some CPUs.

You can check the [Troubleshooting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics#Troubleshooting) section of ArchLinux wiki to check those.

Example of features creating tearing or flickering related issues:

- SNA
- VSYNC
- Panel Self Refresh (PSR)

Check also `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` if your system has put tweaks in here.

Comment: Solution 1 seems to have worked instantly, I tried switching to OpenGL 3.1 but that did not work so switching to xrender worked flawlessly

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by glitching out, especially since the video is down now, but I've found that the video is choppy when using compton, so I had to turn that off.